# How to find rule by number of pfctl output in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, firewall, nat, pfsense

I have the following excerpt from `pfctl -vvss` command:

```
re2 icmp 10.10.0.62:1 <- 192.168.10.56:1       0:0
   age 00:08:30, expires in 00:00:05, 192:7 pkts, 14400:584 bytes, rule 117
   id: 010000005ab2fc3e creatorid: 6261d0b3
re0 icmp 95.84.128.151:47326 (192.168.10.56:1) -> 10.10.0.62:47326       0:0
   age 00:08:30, expires in 00:00:05, 377:4 pkts, 28188:416 bytes, rule 94
   id: 010000005ab2fc3f creatorid: 6261d0b3
```

I think this is undesired behaviour and rules `117` and `94` are incorrect. How to find these rules and fin where did they came from?

What is `creatorid`?

Answer (score 0):

```
pfctl -s rules -vv
```

will output something like:

```
@71 pass out quick on igb1.100 inet from 209.51.186.0/26 to 192.168.0.0/23 no state
[ Evaluations: 1064257   Packets: 354523    Bytes: 149293726   States: 0     ]
[ Inserted: uid 0 pid 1053 State Creations: 0     ]
```

The @71 is the rule number

Answer (score 0):

To see where a rule comes from you can inspect the rules that are created when the configuration file is loaded

```
# pfctl -vv -n -f /etc/pf.conf
```

`-vv` increases the verbosity to also show the rule numbers at the beginning of each rule
`-n`  prevents `pf` from actually loading the rules
`-f`  gives the file from which the rules shall be generated

To me it has proven beneficial to compare this output to the actual content of the configuration file (maybe side by side)

```
# cat /etc/pf.conf
```